# How to copy folder with subfolders using Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
     Copy-Item '\\server-name\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files' –destination 'C:/Program Files' -recurse -container
```

This is the code I am using which works but it creates a folder within Program Files called Program Files when all I need are the contents from the server folder called Program Files put directly into my C: Program Files.

Also if someone could show me how to put this into a function since I'm doing all of these scripts for automating server deployments that would be truly helpful!

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path "C:\FolderA\*" -Destination "C:\FolderB\" -recurse -Force -Verbose`

Comment: don't forget the `*`

Comment: I'm hitting a problem because the network drive isn't mapped so I'm getting an error stating that it doesn't exist. I need to map it using Powershell first but I'm not sure how. Any suggestions? Again I need this to be a reusable function since it will be used for all server setups.

Comment: New-PSDrive -Name "<letter>" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\<upn>"
just an FYI, you could of got that with a simple google search...

Comment: Actually you know what, your code was slightly different than what I found on Google and it worked. Thank you so much I really appreciate it. The full code I got working was Function Copy-ItemUNC{
    
    New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\ServerName\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\"
    
    Copy-Item -Path "\\servername\serverupdates\deploy\Program Files\*" -Destination 'C:/Program Files';
}